# how can I create an horizontal and centered line on fontawesome icon fa fa-circle?

Tags: css, hover, border, center

I'd like to center a hover horizontal bar/border above a menu.
(I have already tried text-align: center and align-content). how could I do this ?

this is my code :

```
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: flex; 
}


nav li {
margin-right: 15px; 
margin-top: 5px;
}


nav a {
font-size: 1.1em;
color: #181818; 
padding-right: 20px; 
padding-top: 30px; 
text-decoration: none;
}


nav a:hover {
color: black; 
border-top: 3px solid #3691b0;
text-align: center; 
}


nav {
position: absolute; 
right: 210px;
top: 20px;  
}

<nav>
  <ul> 
     <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
     <li><a href="nos services.html">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="nos projets.html">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="formulaire.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't center them if you added a nav a {padding-right:20px; } that creates some white space inside `<a>center   </a>` unless you make it both sides equal padding

Try to change it to margin-right:20px;

```css
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: flex; 
}


nav li {
margin-right: 15px; 
margin-top: 5px;
}


nav a {
font-size: 1.1em;
color: #181818; 
margin-right:20px; //padding-right:20px;
padding-top: 30px; 
text-decoration: none;
}


nav a:hover {
color: black; 
border-top: 3px solid #3691b0;
text-align: center; 
}


nav {
position: absolute; 
right: 110px; 
top: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul> 
     <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
     <li><a href="nos services.html">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="nos projets.html">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="formulaire.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```